# Navigation Menu with multiple colored tabs - How to change CSS

Tags: html, navigation

I'm trying to get my navigation menu figured out but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to give each menu item it's own background color, which I've done successfully, but I can't get the colors to space out correctly.  I got a background going through the whole thing (the green and gray in between the menu items) but I'm not sure how to translate that into the menu items auto scaling to match the 940px nav. bar...

Here is a link: www.pancakeweb.com/preschool/test.html

CSS:

```
#header .navigation {
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 940px;
}
#header .navigation > ul:before, #header .navigation > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#header .navigation > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

#header .navigation > ul {
    background: url(../images/bg-navigation.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header .navigation > ul .link1 {
    background: url(../images/bg-navigationb.gif) repeat-x bottom left;

}
#header .navigation > ul .link2 {
    background: url(../images/bg-navigationo.gif) repeat-x bottom left;

}
#header .navigation > ul .link3 {
    background: url(../images/bg-navigationr.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
}
#header .navigation > ul .link4 {
    background: url(../images/bg-navigationg.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
}

#header .navigation > ul > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 35px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
#header .navigation > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Lato-Light';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 52px;
    line-height: 56px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header .navigation > ul > li.selected > a {
    font-family: 'Lato-Black';
}
#header .navigation > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #e2e2e2;
}
#header .navigation > ul > li.booking > a {
    color: #fcac00;
    font-family: 'Lato-Black';
}
#header .navigation > ul > li.booking > a:hover {
    color: #f3be4b;
}
#header .navigation ul ul {
    left: -99999px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    z-index: 5;
}
#header .navigation > ul > li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
}
#header .navigation ul ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 180px;
}
#header .navigation ul ul li:first-child {
    border: 0;
}
#header .navigation ul ul li a {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 23px;
    font-family: 'Lato-Light';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
#header .navigation ul ul li a:hover {
    background:     #fcac00;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="link1">
                <a href="index.php">home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="link2">
                <a href="playbased.php">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="link3">
                <a href="admissions.php">admissions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="link4">
                <a href="teachers.php">Teachers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="link1">
                <a href="community.php">Kindergarten</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="afterschool.php">After School Programs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="springcamps.php">Spring Break Camps</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="camps.php">Summer Camps</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="link2">
                <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.php">Visiting Sudbury</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="map.php">Map & Directions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="donations.php">Giving to Sudbury</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you want to change:

```
#header .navigation > ul > li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 35px;
}
```

I replaced the `35px` side-margins with padding.

Comment: OMG.  Duh.  Thank you so much.  I think I would have fiddled forever and never caught that...